# fetch values from csv with different number of columns in csv, numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading a csv with

```
numpy.genfromtxt(csv_name, delimiter=',')
```

but I am unable to do so because my csv contains different no of columns for each row.

o/p:

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected
 Line #2 (got 8 columns instead of 7)
 Line #3 (got 8 columns instead of 7)
 Line #4 (got 8 columns instead of 7)
 Line #6 (got 8 columns instead of 7)
 Line #7 (got 5 columns instead of 7)
 Line #8 (got 5 columns instead of 7)
 Line #9 (got 5 columns instead of 7)
 Line #10 (got 5 columns instead of 7)
```

Is is possible to do with numpy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import csv with different number of columns per row using Pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020216/import-csv-with-different-number-of-columns-per-row-using-pandas)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable Number of Columns in genfromtxt() in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152432/variable-number-of-columns-in-genfromtxt-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html, you can do it using the `filling_values` argument of `genfromtxt`.

Otherwise, you could use this answer: [Python: How to read a data file with uneven number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823037/python-how-to-read-a-data-file-with-uneven-number-of-columns)

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok to restrict the data that is read to the common number of columns across all rows, you can use `usecols` to explicitly select the columns to read, e.g.:

```
numpy.genfromtxt(csv_name, delimiter=',', usecols=range(4))
```

Comment: This is probably related to the actual data in your CSV-file. A sample of the data is needed to clarify this.

Comment: You may need to specify the `dtype`